Relation between elements with fixed exponent over different $\mathbb{Z}^\times_p$
A primitive root $h$ of $n$ is a generator of the cyclic modulo multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}^\times_n$.
Suppose, $\mathbb{P}_{\langle 2\rangle,N}=\{p_i <N\mid \langle 2\rangle=\mathbb{Z}^\times_{p_i}\}$ denotes the set of all primes $p_i<N$ that have a primtive root $2$. Let,  $2^k\equiv x_i \mod{p_i}$, for some fixed even integer $k\gg\log{p_i}$ for all $p_i \in\mathbb{P}_{\langle 2\rangle,N}$.
My questions are,

Is there any upper and lower bound on each $x_i$, even asymptotically? or do they have some special form?
Is there any relation between any arbitrary pair $(x_i,x_j)$ for $i\ne j$?

In short, is it possible to predict $x_i$ even before $p_i$ is specified?

If I understand your question right, $x_i \geq 3$ should be the best possible lower bound (since $1$ and $2$ are impossible or obvious reasons). We can find examples where this bound is sharp by factoring $2^k-3$ - many prime factors should have $2$ as a primitive root. Some examples with $k/\log p$ small are $5,13,29, 61, 509$.

Thank you professor @WillSawin for this answer. If I understood correctly, in other words do you want say that $x_i=3$ for a non-negligible fraction of primes that have $2$ as one of their primitive roots?

Not necessarily a non-negligible fraction in the sense of positive density, but I would expect this does happen for infinitely many primes.

Yes, that is correct. Thank you again. It could be really helpful if this fraction could be expressed as a function of $N$. I think it needs a separate question.

Isn't $p_i$ a readily available upper bound for $x_i$?

@MaxAlekseyev Yes, $2<x_i< p_i$ trivially. An $\mathcal{O}(\log{p_i})$ bound would be more meaningful,

For $k=(p_i-1)/2$ (and its odd multiples), we have $x_i=p_i-1$, which shows that no better upper bound is possible.

@MaxAlekseyev Thanks for this calrification. It is correct.
